# paypal addresses

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, paypal, address

I have a problem where we are using Magento, IWD onepagecheckout and PayPal Express. The problem is it seems to send the shipping address rather than the default address when going through to Paypal.

It seems to be a standard problem but I can't seem to find a fix.

Tried altering firstline in cart.php to (but just caused error): `$this->_salesEntity->getBillingAddress()` : `$this->_salesEntity->getBillingAddress();`

```
            $this->_salesEntity->getBillingAddress() : $this->_salesEntity->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingDescription = $address->getShippingDescription();
        $this->_totals = array (
            self::TOTAL_SUBTOTAL => $this->_salesEntity->getBaseSubtotal(),
            self::TOTAL_TAX      => $address->getBaseTaxAmount(),
            self::TOTAL_SHIPPING => $address->getBaseShippingAmount(),
            self::TOTAL_DISCOUNT => abs($address->getBaseDiscountAmount()),
        );
        $this->_applyHiddenTaxWorkaround($address);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!!  See below: -

find `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php`

change

```
$address = $isOrderVirtual ? $order->getBillingAddress() : $order->getShippingAddress();
if ($isOrderVirtual) {
$api->setNoShipping(true);
} elseif ($address->validate()) {
$api->setAddress($address);
}
```

to

```
$address =$order->getBillingAddress();
if ($address->validate())
{
$api->setAddress($address);
}
```

Comment: Do not change in magento core files. Move this file to local codePool or override it